# links menu showing on site

Tags: wordpress, menu, hyperlink

I hope you can help me,

please take a look at my company’s site http://www.fiestafranchise.com
it seems to be a small issue with the menus when you jump from one to another page there is the list on the menu (blue text) on the left side of the site that shows momentarily and then goes away. any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: please make future questions self contained; this "come to my site and tell me what is wrong" is **not** a good way to ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your source code, I think your problem is you have a lot of external HTTP requests. I count 18 separate javascript files and 9 CSS files.

Another factor is that all your javascript is called in the head. Meaning they must all load BEFORE your markup is rendered. The currently accepted practice is to put all your javascript at the bottom of the document right before the closing of the body tag.

Finally, you should really be combining all your javascript into a single minified file. Same for your CSS (though keep your CSS within the head tag).

Hope that helps!

Comment: that sounds great! what you just said.. I'm lost in regards to java, css all you mention. if you guide me in the correct direction will be appreciated

Comment: I take it then that you did not build the site? Do you have a developer in house or did you use a contractor? It would be best to take these suggestions to him/her for implementation. Or if you'd like, I am available as a contractor/consultant. :)